# Breadcrumb changing field name

Tags: umbraco, partial-views, umbraco7, breadcrumbs

My breadcrumb consists of the following:

Website > 1st site > 2nd site.

I want to change "Website" to "Home" and this is my code:

```
@if (!Umbraco.AssignedContentItem.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("Home"))
    {
        <div class="breadcrumb" itemprop="breadcrumb">
            @foreach (var level in Model.Content.Ancestors().Where("Visible").OrderBy("Level"))
            {
                if (Umbraco.AssignedContentItem.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("Website"))
                {
                    <p>test</p><a class="breadcrumb" href="@level.Url">Home</a>
                }
                else
                {
                    <a class="breadcrumb" href="@level.Url">@level.Name</a>
                }
                <span>&gt;</span>
            }
            @CurrentPage.Name
        </div>
    }
```

The first .Equals makes sure the breadcrumb is hidden on the homepage as the documentalias of my homepage is "Home".

The second .Equal should change "Website" into "Home". "Website" is also my DocumentAlias.

I am using Umbraco version 7.7.2

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Comment: Do you want to change the label "Website" to "Home"? Then you should change the following html <a class="breadcrumb" href="@level.Url">Home</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `Model.DocumentTypeAlias` to check the document type of the current page.

Also, it might be easier to check which level you're on rather than checking the current document type alias: `Model.Level == 1` would check if you're at the root (the homepage).

When you're doing `if (Umbraco.AssignedContentItem.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("Website"))`, I would imagine this is testing the document type of the current page, where as you want to test the current item in the foreach. Try:

```
if (level.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("Website"))
{
    ...
```

Full fixed example:

```
@if (Model.Level != 1)
{
    <div class="breadcrumb" itemprop="breadcrumb">
        @foreach (var level in Model.Content.Ancestors().Where("Visible").OrderBy("Level"))
        {
            if (level.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("Website"))
            {
                <p>test</p><a class="breadcrumb" href="@level.Url">Home</a>
            }
            else
            {
                <a class="breadcrumb" href="@level.Url">@level.Name</a>
            }
            <span>&gt;</span>
        }
        @CurrentPage.Name
    </div>
}
```

Please note, if your page inherits from `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage` rather than `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage`, you will need to write `Model.Content` rather than just `Model` to access the current page content.

Comment: This got it working! Thank you! 

I had to change the @if code back to my original one so it wouldn't show on the first page. The rest is working flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but, to avoid using doctypes checking and all that logic you could do the following:

Create a 'Title' property in a doctype. This can be a composition or from a inherited doctype, or even you could create your own base model for Models Builder.

Create an extension method like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string TitleOrName(this IPublishedContent content)
    {
         if (content.HasValue("title")) return content.GetPropertyValue<string>("title");
         else return content.Name;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it on your breadcrumb like this:

```
@if (!Umbraco.AssignedContentItem.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("Home"))
    {
        <div class="breadcrumb" itemprop="breadcrumb">
            @foreach (var level in Model.Content.Ancestors().Where("Visible").OrderBy("Level"))
            {

                    <a class="breadcrumb" href="@level.Url">@level.TitleOrName()</a>                    
                <span>&gt;</span> //I would include this using CSS
            }
            @CurrentPage.TitleOrName()
        </div>
    }
```